# Keep different variable's state in multiple anonymous asynchronous functions in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, scope, anonymous-function

I'm at loss at how to describe this without code, so here it goes:

```
$('.colors').each(function() {
    $.getJSON('my.json', function(data) {
        $(this).css('color', data.color);
    });
});
```

I want the body of the `getJSON` callback to reference the value of `this` in the parent (`each` callback) scope.

This code will not work, because `this` will not be what it was outside the `getJSON` callback. Even if I try to place it in a variable, it will not work because only one variable will be shared by all callbacks, instead of one per iteration of the loop.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
$('.colors').each(function() {
    $.getJSON('my.json', $.proxy(function(data) {
        $(this).css('color', data.color);
    }, this));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could capture it in a closure:

```
$('.colors').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.getJSON('my.json', function(data) {
        $this.css('color', data.color);
    });
});
```

or:

```
$('.colors').each(function() {
    $.getJSON(
        'my.json', 
        (function(element) {
            return function(data) {
                element.css('color', data.color);
            };
        })(this)
    );
});
```

Comment: I'd try this, but Yoshi's answer uses jQuery and it's just perfect. +1 anyway.